# Update a column values based on two other column's complex conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, group-by

For the `DataFrame df` below

```
df = pd.DataFrame([('Tesla','Model3', '-', 'Motor'),
                  ('Tesla', 'ModelS', '-', 'MotorMD3'),
                  ('Tesla', 'ModelX', '-', 'MotorMD3'),
                  ('Tesla', 'ModelY', '-', 'Motor'),
                  ('Jeep',  'Wrangler','Grouped','Engine'),
                  ('Jeep',  'Compass', 'Grouped','EngineMD3'),
                  ('Jeep',  'Patriot', 'Grouped','Engine'),
                  ('Jeep',  'Cherokee','Grouped','Engine'),
                  ('Ford',  'Mustang', 'Grouped','Engine'),
                  ('Ford',  'F150',     'Grouped','Engine')  ],columns=['Make','Model','Status','Type'])


df
     Make    Model        Status    Type
0   Tesla   Model3             -    Motor
1   Tesla   ModelS             -    MotorMD3
2   Tesla   ModelX             -    MotorMD3
3   Tesla   ModelY             -    Motor
4   Jeep    Wrangler     Grouped    Engine
5   Jeep    Compass      Grouped    EngineMD3
6   Jeep    Patriot      Grouped    Engine
7   Jeep    Cherokee     Grouped    Engine
8   Ford    Mustang      Grouped    Engine
9   Ford    F150         Grouped    Engine
```

I am trying to update the column `Type` with `EngineMD3` for all same `Make`, if `EngineMD3` is present in any of the `Models` in that `Make`, and if the `Status` is `Grouped` for that `Make`. But if the `Status` is not `Grouped`, `Type` should be kept as such for each `Models`. If 'EngineMD3' is not present the `Type` should be maintained as `Engine`.

For instance, `Tesla` is not `Grouped`, so each model keeps their `Type` the same. But `Jeep` is `Grouped`, and `Compass` is having its `Type` as `EngineMD3`, so `EngineMD3` is updated as the `Type` for all `Jeep` `Models`. `Ford` is `Grouped` but none of the `Models` have type `EngineMD3` so `Type` is kept as `Engine`

Expected output

```
     Make    Model    Status       Type
0   Tesla   Model3      -           Motor  #For Tesla Type is maintained for each model seperately since it is not grouped
1   Tesla   ModelS      -         MotorMD3
2   Tesla   ModelX      -         MotorMD3
3   Tesla   ModelY      -            Motor
4   Jeep    Wrangler   Grouped   EngineMD3 #Since Jeep is grouped, all its Type is changed to EngineMD3 since one of the model had EngineMD3
5   Jeep    Compass    Grouped   EngineMD3
6   Jeep    Patriot    Grouped   EngineMD3
7   Jeep    Cherokee   Grouped   EngineMD3
8   Ford    Mustang    Grouped      Engine #Even though Ford is grouped, since there is no EngineMD3 the Type is maintained as Engine.
9   Ford    F150       Grouped      Engine
```

In other words,
The conditions are for all the `makes`(eg. Jeeps) If the `make` is grouped and if `FD3` is appended to any of the model `types`, then all the grouped models in the same `make` will have the FD3 appended to them

I tried to use `np.select` to update the `Type` column with multiple conditions but I couldn't give a condition to select all same `Make` at once and update the `Type`. Please do help I am running out of options here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.loc[df.Status.eq('Grouped'), 'Type'] = df[df.Status.eq('Grouped')].groupby('Make').Type.transform(
    lambda x: 'EngineMD3' if x.eq('EngineMD3').any() else x)
```

```
    Make     Model   Status       Type
0  Tesla    Model3        -      Motor
1  Tesla    ModelS        -   MotorMD3
2  Tesla    ModelX        -   MotorMD3
3  Tesla    ModelY        -      Motor
4   Jeep  Wrangler  Grouped  EngineMD3
5   Jeep   Compass  Grouped  EngineMD3
6   Jeep   Patriot  Grouped  EngineMD3
7   Jeep  Cherokee  Grouped  EngineMD3
8   Ford   Mustang  Grouped     Engine
9   Ford      F150  Grouped     Engine
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm no python expert, I'm sure there are more optimal solutions... But here is one.

1. Checking the length of the query  > 0.
2. If it is > 0, then we store the value of Make that satisfies the conditions you mentioned in y variable.
3. Then we replace the Type of that specific Make.

```
if len(df.query("Status == 'Grouped' & Type.str.startswith('EngineMD3')")) > 0:
    x = df.query("Status == 'Grouped' & Type.str.startswith('EngineMD3')")['Make'].values
    for i in range(len(x)):
        y = x[i]
        df['Type'].loc[df['Make'] == y] = 'EnginerMD3'
    display(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
def process(g):
    if sum(g.Status=='Grouped')>0:
        g['Type'] = 'EngineMD3' if sum(g.Type=='EngineMD3')>0 else 'Engine'
    return g
df.groupby('Make').apply(process)
```

Output:

```
    Make    Model       Status  Type
0   Tesla   Model3      -       Motor
1   Tesla   ModelS      -       MotorMD3
2   Tesla   ModelX      -       MotorMD3
3   Tesla   ModelY      -       Motor
4   Jeep    Wrangler    Grouped EngineMD3
5   Jeep    Compass     Grouped EngineMD3
6   Jeep    Patriot     Grouped EngineMD3
7   Jeep    Cherokee    Grouped EngineMD3
8   Ford    Mustang     Grouped Engine
9   Ford    F150        Grouped Engine
```

Comment: This is a nice way to approach the problem but my original DataFrame is a huge one with lot more rows and columns, so I am afraid if I use group by whether that will ruin the DataFrame structure of indexes. Is there any other way to do this without the groupby?

Comment: Hmm I don't think we can do that without group by. @Алексей Р's answer is optimal IMO.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the following function :

```py
def trans(s_1, s_2, s_3):
    
    Make_values, new_col = [], []
          
    for i in range(len(s_1)):
        if s_3[i]=="EngineMD3" and s_2[i]=="Grouped":
            Make_values.append(s_1[i])
          
    for i in range(len(Make_values)):
          
        for j in range(len(s_3)):
          
            if s_1[j]==Make_values[i]:
          
                new_col.append("EngineMD3")
            else:
                new_col.append(s_3[j])
    return new_col
```

And we apply it:

```py
df['Type']=trans(df['Make'], df['Status'], df['Type'])
```